# Debian mirror is out of control

Tags: linux, debian, debian-squeeze

I've inherited a system (Debian Squeeze) that has a Debian mirror set up within it, which is something I have basically no experience with. The problem with it is, it has completely filled up it's partition. Adding to the partition results in it's filling up the extra room - it's basically at 100%, all the time.

I've looked at the ftpsync.conf, and it appears to have everything other than amd64 excluded, so theoretically, it should only be taking up ~92 GB, and yet it's currently sitting at 383 GB:

```
383G  383G  556K 100% /srv/debian-mirror
```

Looking at the current list of architectures (https://www.debian.org/mirror/size), I'm wondering if the issue could be that my ftpsync.conf doesn't have the right values? Perhaps the list that I have is out of date? The following is what I have in this conf:

```
ARCH_EXCLUDE="alpha arm armel hppa hurd-i386 i386 ia64 kfreebsd-amd64 kfreebsd-i386 m68k mipsel mips powerpc s390 sh sparc source"
```

If that's not the issue, any advice on where to look would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe sync is only adding new files and not deleting files removed from upstream mirrors? Did you check that?

Comment: It's hard to say. Looking at the logs, I keep seeing errors, because the partition is completely full. I'm currently clearing out some room so rsync can populate it - that should give me more to go on. Thank you!

Comment: Just take a look at some subdir, for example pool/l/ and take a look at some package name like linux-image and try to see if there are multiple versions on your local disk that aren't available online.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to provide an answer. Answers should be posted as such.

Comment: Done. Thanks Michael, I can see why that would be the preferred method.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue was an improperly configured ARCH_EXCLUDE - some of the architectures were listed incorrectly, possibly some of them changed or were deprecated over time (it hadn't been modified in years), and now it's synced a couple of times, and is holding fast at 108 GB. The ARCH_EXCLUDE is now configured thusly:

```
ARCH_EXCLUDE="source all arm64 armel armhf hurd-i386 i386 ia64 kfreebsd-amd64 kfreebsd-i386 mips mipsel powerpc ppc64el s390 s390x sparc"
```